# Is the Philippine corpus known as Palito still available for download online?

Tags: corpora, resource-request

I have visited http://ccs.dlsu.edu.ph:8086/Palito/, but it is no longer online. [SEAlang](http://sealang.net/tagalog/corpus.htm) has the same content, I think, but it isn't downloadable.

Is it still available for download online?

Answer (score 1):

We are currently working to revive the said project. I'm not sure though if the content is still available on our local intranet.

Comment: Please disclose if you are affiliated with the project. Knowing that you represent an authoritative source would be certainly helpful.